# sending mail with drf django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to send mail after signup from django drf:

settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

serializers.py:

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

      def create(self, validated_data):
          user = UserModel.objects.create(email=validated_data['email'])
          user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
          user.save()
          to_mail = user.email
          send_mail('Subject here','Here is the message.','myemail@gmail.com',['to_mail',],fail_silently=False,)
          return user
     class Meta:
           model = UserModel       
           fields = ( "id", "email", "password", )
```

im'm getting this error:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused at /api/registration/

{'=?utf-8?q?to=5Fmail?=': (553, b'5.1.3 The recipient address <=?utf-8?q?to=5Fmail?=> is not a valid RFC-5321\n5.1.3 address. u2sm31792629pgc.19 - gsmtp')}
```

i'm even tried to send mail to different mail but i'm still gettings this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to Enable IMAP and/or POP3. If you are getting the same error after enabling IMAP or POP3 try the code by removing email_backend.

```
#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Comment: got it working there was also error in send_mail to_mail should't be string